# Camera live scanning iOS

Tags: ios

I am developing an iOS application where I need to do some object live scanning. For this I need to take 3 or 4 frames per second in example. Here is my code for creating capture session:

```
// Create an AVCaptureSession
    AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    // Find a suitable AVCaptureDevice
    AVCaptureDevice *photoCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // Create and add an AVCaptureDeviceInput
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:photoCaptureDevice error:&error];
    if(videoInput){
        [captureSession addInput:videoInput];
    }

    // Create and add an AVCaptureVideoDataOutput
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    // we want BGRA, both CoreGraphics and OpenGL work well with 'BGRA'
    NSDictionary *rgbOutputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
    [videoOutput setVideoSettings:rgbOutputSettings];

    // Configure your output, and start the session
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

    if(videoOutput){
        [captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];
    }

    [captureSession startRunning];


    // Setting up the preview layer for the camera
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    previewLayer.frame = cameraViewCanvas.bounds;

    // ADDING FINAL VIEW layer TO THE MAIN VIEW sublayer
    [cameraViewCanvas.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

And delegate method which is called on queue:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
    if(isCapturing){
        NSLog(@"output");

        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
        CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer options:(NSDictionary *)attachments];

        UIImage *newFrame = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage];
        [self showImage:newFrame];
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot see the image on a screen, no errors and warnings, but image is not shown. My question is - am I on the right path, what needs to be fixed in my code to show the image on the screen?

Comment: Would you provide more info about your `cameraViewCanvas`? Where is it defined and initialized and so on...

Comment: It is just a `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *cameraViewCanvas;` to show the camera's video output, it is not for the whole size of the window, so I can add some other objects, i.e. UIImageView to preview what frames have I taken yet.

Comment: So you added it in the InterfaceBuilder to the main View?

Comment: yep, dont't think that problem is caused by it, because camera layer looks ok, as I suggest there is smth connected with conversion from CIImage to UIImage, there were some question on this topic and I used some advices from them, but it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Belated, but the issue is likely due to not setting the image in the main thread (captureOutput is called in a separate dispatch queue you've created, most likely).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self showImage:newFrame];
});
```

or

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showImage:) newFrame waitUntilDone:YES];
```